# srand(seed) produces different values on different servers

Tags: php

The function my site uses for encoding/decoding cookie data utilizes rand(). It's not an ideal method at all, but it's the default cipher function in CakePHP 1.2, so I'm stuck using it for now, unless I want to invalidate all my user's cookies (and I really don't right now).

The problem is that I'm moving the site to a different server, and the new server is unable to decode cookies set by the old server because rand() produces different values even though both servers use srand(seed) with the same seed. I imagine the problem is that the two servers are using different internal php functions for generating the random numbers, as mentioned in this cakephp bug regarding the cipher function: http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/1524-securitycipher-is-platform-dependent

I'm wondering how I can alter the cipher function on the new server to be able to decode cookies correctly that were set by the older server. Any way to force php to use the same internal random function or something?

Comment: Are both servers running the same version of PHP? Are they both running on the same OS?

Comment: Old server is Centos 4.7 and PHP 5.2.14 and new server is Centos 5.7 and PHP 5.2.17.

Comment: The difference in platform is a likely culprit. Since it looks like the decision on srand algorithm is being made in the C code for the PHP implementation, it might not be a possibility to choose your own. You'd either have to  see if the functions that PHP is using internally are provided in the PHP API (which it doesn't look like they are) or figure out how PHP is making the decision based on platform (by checking out the C code). The easiest solution would probably be to match the platform - perhaps if you use the same PHP version, you will get the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I am inclined to think that might be a desired behaviour. So says http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-srand.php ( I know yours is srand not mt_srand but still ) :

> Identical seeds no longer produce the same sequence of values they did in previous versions. This behavior is not expected to change again, but it is considered unsafe to rely upon it nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I had sort of the same problem, here [I link my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27157896/use-of-bccmath-library-in-php-give-different-result-depending-in-the-operative-s), I know this is very old question but hopes someone find a solution in the future coming here. As the first answer said @chx, it was all about changing from srand() to mt_srand().