# Use of BCCMATH library in php give different result depending in the operative system

Tags: php

here is my problem. I am using [BCMATH functions of PHP (here the class I use, and the function Base_Math::obfuscate())](http://pastebin.com/WprBTLY1) to obfuscate some urls, ids, etc and deobfuscate them.

I am actually programming over windows 8.1 x64 with the last version of XAMPP. Recently I created a virtual machine in my computer wtih vmware based on centOS 6.6 x64 which is the operative system I will have online, to debug problems compabilities between operative system and to have a stage environment to make updates faster.

The problem comes when I go to the vm environment, the functions used from BCMATH gives me as a result different values as it does in windows environment. One of my friends warn me about this could happen but I love risk and lose tons of hours programming :|

What I don't know, if this problem comes because of the operative system, because of the hardware itself or what? Can I modified the function so it gives me back always the same result? If it can't be what would you say it is a good solution to obfuscate your database entities ID?

This is the way I use the method:

```
//obfuscate number 5
Math_Base::obfuscate(5,false,32,'OndZLj3mby9GpDtbrzDVGPkWR1J1dlC9JPIcsMe1l0YX8lzONTVlkCzDzPb9PJR');
//it returns on windows 8: CsQNlnY5dXMKJXYLFgzxZT85HTzPb2FQ 
//in centos YBs1DMzFdhV5JhzlG7NvtxfFmxNkrTGs
```

Comment: Can you give sample strings? And the way you use the class..

Comment: That code isn't using just the [bcmath functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php). It relies on PHPs native integers and math mostly (susceptible to 32/64 bit differences). It's just an elaborate `base_convert` encoding.

Comment: @mario both system are 64 bits, also say, that I think it is because of bcmath but I may be wrong, I am just not sure about it

Comment: Read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058871/srandseed-produces-different-values-on-different-servers the problem is `srand` function in `destination_base` and .. `different processors/processor speeds/operating systems/OS releases/PHP releases/webserver software may generate different sequences` and the string shuffle gives different results. Also, just to understand the problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958795/different-rand-results-on-windows-and-linux

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Cheery](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1164491/cheery) because what he/she said gave me the answer to the problem in the third comment of my question. It was all about srand(). Since I didn't create this class, my great [friend](https://github.com/javiermarinros) did modified it for me. [This is the result class](http://pastebin.com/w8i4Q5Ht)

He did change this part (causing the problem):

```
 if ($this->_key !== null) {
     //Mezclar los caracteres base usando la clave
     srand(crc32($this->_key));
     $this->_base = str_shuffle($this->_base_original);
     srand(); //Restaurar semilla aleatoria por defecto
 }
```

For this one:

```
if ($this->_key !== null) {
    //Mezclar los caracteres base usando la clave
    mt_srand(crc32($this->_key));
    $chars = Str::chars($this->_base_original);
    for($i = count($chars) - 1; $i > 0; --$i) {
        $j = mt_rand(0, $i);
        if($i !== $j) {
            list($chars[$i], $chars[$j]) = array($chars[$j], $chars[$i]);
        }
    }
    $this->_base= join('', $chars);
    mt_srand();//Restaurar semilla aleatoria por defecto
}
```

So he did avoid any compatibility problem between platforms.

Thanks to everyone who helped here.